# Does Happy! season 2 end on a cliff hanger?

Tags: happy

I've just finished watching season 1 of Happy! And it's ended in a good place. I've heard that season 3 was cancelled, does season 2 end on a cliffhanger? (No spoilers please!)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a cliffhanger, but it does leave a room for a next season.  You shouldn't feel disappointed that things are left unresolved, but you might wonder about the future fate of main characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you heard the rumours are true, the show [was cancelled](https://tvseriesfinale.com/tv-show/happy-cancelled-by-syfy-no-season-three-for-christopher-meloni-series/) for bad ratings likely (apparently 50~% drop in viewership) also a 14 month gap between seasons didn’t help.

The ending of season 2 (and points from season 1) set things up to make season 3 a probably *very* wacky season indeed.